# How to create multiple tables from one module in MVC view?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to create multiple tables from one module in mvc view , I created 2 header and 2 foreach  but when i run the view its not seperated and second set of columns header not appeared only one set of header columns at the beginning of view , How to seperate the view and show multiple tables include header and columns ?

This is my View code :

```
@model IEnumerable<AljawdahNewSite.Models.Orders_Tables>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details1";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
    var ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

Then this is first table :

```
@if (ids.Contains(Model.First().labCashView.DEPTID.GetValueOrDefault()))
{
 <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane container active p-0" style="margin-left:15px">
         <hr />
         <dl class="horizontal" style="border:solid">
             <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Patient_Name)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Patient_Name)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Customer_Name)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Customer_Name)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Patient_No)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Patient_No)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:0px;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Collection_Date)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Collection_Date)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.SEX)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.SEX)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:60px;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Receiving_Date)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Receiving_Date)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.AGE)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.AGE)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:60px;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Report_Date)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Report_Date)</dd>
             <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.order_number)</dt>
             <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.order_number)</dd>
         </dl>
     
     
         <table id="menu" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
             <tr>

                 <td> test name    </td>
                 <td> result  </td>
                 <td> From Range   </td>
                 <td> To Range </td>
                 <td> Other Range    </td>
                 <td> Report Date  </td>


             </tr>
             <tbody>
             @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.labCashView.DEPTID.GetValueOrDefault())))
             {
                     <tr>

                         <td>@item.labCashView.Test_Name</td>
                         <td>@item.labCashView.Result</td>
                         <td>@item.labCashView.Low_Range</td>
                         <td>@item.labCashView.High_Range</td>
                         <td style="width:20%">@item.labCashView.Text_Range</td>
                         <td>@item.labCashView.Report_Date.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>


                     </tr>

             }
                 </tbody>


         </table>
         <hr />


     </div>
 </div>

}
```

And second table :

```
     @if (Model.First().labCashView.DEPTID == 6)
 {   <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane container fade p-0" style="margin-left:15px">
             <hr />
            
                 <dl class="horizontal" style="border:solid">
                     <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Patient_Name)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Patient_Name)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Customer_Name)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Customer_Name)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Patient_No)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Patient_No)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:0px;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Collection_Date)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Collection_Date)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.SEX)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.SEX)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:60px;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Receiving_Date)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Receiving_Date)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.AGE)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.AGE)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:60px;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.Report_Date)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.Report_Date)</dd>
                     <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;color:blue;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labCashView.order_number)</dt>
                     <dd style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labCashView.order_number)</dd>
                 </dl>
            
             
         
        
             <table id="menu1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                 <tr>

                     <td> test name    </td>
                     <td> result  </td>
                     <td> From Range   </td>
                     <td> To Range </td>
                     <td> Other Range    </td>
                     <td> Report Date  </td>


                 </tr>
                 <tbody>
                     @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.labCashView.DEPTID == 6))
                     {
                         <tr>

                             <td>@item.labCashView.TEXT</td>
                             <td>@item.labCashView.TEST_RESULT</td>
                             <td>@item.labCashView.UNIT</td>
                             <td>@item.labCashView.Text_Range</td>
                             <td>@item.labCashView.Report_Date.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>


                         </tr>
                     }
                 </tbody>

             </table>
             <hr />



         </div>
    </div>

 }
```

when run the view in browser its appear one header and one table second header and second foreach not appeared  :

First table appeared correct like the image :

[image]

How to separate 2 tables and show each header and data in view each in one page ?

Comment: Looks like your 2nd table only has (5) columns on the `foreach`. Also the `tbody` is outside the loop (2nd table iteration), unlike the first code loop (which has the `tbody` inside the iteration).

Comment: @RobScott why it should be same (5) columns ? and about tbody i added it later on when i faced this issue also without tbody same output

Comment: The second table's use of the iteration inside <tbody> is the correct structure. Match the first table's code (one <tbody> with the iteration of multiple <tr> elements inside that). Also, using the browser's developer tools will be helpful in diagnosing this issue (e.g. RIGHT+CLICK in the table and "inspect")

Comment: @Abdullah what are the values of `ids` collection? you have *if(first Condition) and else if(second condition)* so one table will be appeared for both conditions. and that depends on `DEPTID` value. one more information, use *Partial views* to factorize the html code.

Comment: @Sajid ids is variable hold department id i have 7 department and departments 1,2,3 and 4 has same result report department 5 and 6 and 7 each department have different result form , so i need to collect them in one view . ok i will check partial view how to use it , and you are correct inspect show all rows under one table , i changed it but result still same i made 2 if statement

Comment: ok, so if i understand, ids contains 1,2,3,4 and you have other tables for 5,6 and 7. if yes, so you don't need to use `else if`, just like `if(condition for 1,2,3,4) ==> first table` another `if(condition of 6) ==> second table` to show all tables and check data in the controller for each grouped DPT..

Comment: @Sajid yes right but because i cannot collect the all the tables and loop it i made SQL SERVER view and UNION ALL 5 SELECT in one SQL SERVER VIEW labCashView

Comment: @Abdullah to construct each table, filter for DPT before loop, like : `first table 
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.labCashView.DEPTID.GetValueOrDefault())))
{
.... 
}
second table 
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(x=>x.labCashView.DEPTID == 6)))
{
.... 
}
....` if you don't use this, will show all data in each table

Comment: @Sajid now only first foreach appeared second not appeared after added Model.Where

Comment: @Abdullah do you have DPT equals *6* in the collection?try this : `foreach (var item in Model.Where(x=>x.labCashView.DEPTID == 6)) { .... }` i have added a parenthese :)

Comment: @Sajid yes when i execute the view in SQL SERVER its there , and before added this condition model.where some data appeared

Comment: @Abdullah, it's normal, why you want check for DPT and you want use the same data for all DPT like tables? how you can make difference between tables for each DPT? you must filter for each DPT no?

Comment: @Sajid its not same data departments from 1 to 4 same data and same table but 5,6,7 defferent data and tables and structure , i need like this post multiple tables in single view but the point in one foreach i need to select data from multiple tables this will solve my issue all posts that use multiple tables in single view in foreach loop they use only one table per foreach loop https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-multiple-tables-in-a-single-view-in-asp-net-mvc/ i can use this post if i can select in one foreach select data from 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create the class :

```
public class TablesModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Model1> model1 { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Model2> model2 { get; set; }
    }
```

2- create the controller if you want to make relation with id use `.Where()`and to use relation with another table you can use `.Include()`:

```
public ActionResult Index()  
        {  
            var tables = new TablesModel
            {  
                model1 =db.Model1.ToList(),  
                model2 =db.Model2.ToList(),  

            };  
            return View(tables);
```

3- create empty view for controller and use like the following code :

```
<div class="tab-content">  

        <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">model list</h5>  
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
            <thead class="thead-dark text-white">  
                <tr>  
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.model1.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>  
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.model1.FirstOrDefault().Age)</th>  

                </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>  
                @foreach (var item in Model.model1 )  
                {  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>@item.Name</td>  
                        <td>@item.Age</td>  

                    </tr>  
                }  
            </tbody>  
        </table>  
    </div> 

<div class="tab-content">  

        <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">model list</h5>  
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
            <thead class="thead-dark text-white">  
                <tr>  
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.model2.FirstOrDefault().Address)</th>  
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.model2.FirstOrDefault().Mobile)</th>  

                </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>  
                @foreach (var item in Model.model2 )  
                {  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>@item.Address</td>  
                        <td>@item.Mobile</td>  

                    </tr>  
                }  
            </tbody>  
        </table>  
    </div>
```